# My problem is the error says: "attempted to nil with nil"

Tags: lua, roblox

game.ReplicatedStorage.bruh2:FireServer(Players[RobieLuis1111alt], "Scrap Metal")

Comment: Help plz  plz plz

Comment: Well, both `Players` and `RobieLuis1111alt` is nil. Verify that you set them. I assume you meant `"RobieLuis1111alt"` as a string, so that should be one of the nils.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "RobieLuis1111alt" is your username, and that needs to be a string.
Players is also undefined and needs pointing to exactly what you want, in this case, the players service.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

game.ReplicatedStorage.bruh2:FireServer(Players["RobieLuis1111alt"], "Scrap Metal")
```